# NPM install/start Errors

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I can't make an `npm install` or `npm start command`. When I try `npm install` the console returns:

```
undefined postinstall C:\Users\Aristophanes 
> cd packages/react-error-overlay/ && yarn build:prod  
bash: line 0: cd: packages/react-error-overlay/: No such file or directory 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! undefined postinstall: `cd packages/react-error-overlay/ && yarn build:prod` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the undefined postinstall script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Log link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xckz3t8e4vbyur/2018-11-08T07_01_43_968Z-debug.log?dl=0

Firstly, I'm not really sure why it's looking for a `packages/react-error-overlay/` directory, but I think the console might be referring to this directory on my computer at

> C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-error-overlay

As that's the only `react-error-overlay` directory with the `packages/` prefix in its path. If I open that directory in cmd and try `npm start` I get this error:

```
> react-error-overlay@4.0.0 start C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-error-overlay 
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node build.js --watch  

bash: cross-env: command not found 
npm ERR! file bash npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno ENOENT 
npm ERR! syscall spawn 
npm ERR! react-error-overlay@4.0.0 start: cross-env NODE_ENV=development node build.js --watch 
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-error-overlay@4.0.0 start script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. 
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Log link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibh87l08d65vcq5/2018-11-08T06_59_07_881Z-debug.log?dl=0

Any ideas how I could fix this? Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "version": "6.4.1",
  "name": "npm",
  "description": "a package manager for JavaScript",
  "keywords": [
    "install",
    "modules",
    "package manager",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "config": {
    "publishtest": false
  },
  "homepage": "https://docs.npmjs.com/",
  "author": "Isaac Z. Schlueter <i@izs.me> (http://blog.izs.me)",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/npm/cli"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://npm.community/c/bugs"
  },
  "directories": {
    "bin": "./bin",
    "doc": "./doc",
    "lib": "./lib",
    "man": "./man"
  },
  "main": "./lib/npm.js",
  "bin": {
    "npm": "./bin/npm-cli.js",
    "npx": "./bin/npx-cli.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "JSONStream": "^1.3.4",
    "abbrev": "~1.1.1",
    "ansicolors": "~0.3.2",
    "ansistyles": "~0.1.3",
    "aproba": "~1.2.0",
    "archy": "~1.0.0",
    "bin-links": "^1.1.2",
    "bluebird": "~3.5.1",
    "byte-size": "^4.0.3",
    "cacache": "^11.2.0",
    "call-limit": "~1.1.0",
    "chownr": "~1.0.1",
    "ci-info": "^1.4.0",
    "cli-columns": "^3.1.2",
    "cli-table3": "^0.5.0",
    "cmd-shim": "~2.0.2",
    "columnify": "~1.5.4",
    "config-chain": "~1.1.11",
    "detect-indent": "~5.0.0",
    "detect-newline": "^2.1.0",
    "dezalgo": "~1.0.3",
    "editor": "~1.0.0",
    "figgy-pudding": "^3.4.1",
    "find-npm-prefix": "^1.0.2",
    "fs-vacuum": "~1.2.10",
    "fs-write-stream-atomic": "~1.0.10",
    "gentle-fs": "^2.0.1",
    "glob": "~7.1.2",
    "graceful-fs": "~4.1.11",
    "has-unicode": "~2.0.1",
    "hosted-git-info": "^2.7.1",
    "iferr": "^1.0.2",
    "inflight": "~1.0.6",
    "inherits": "~2.0.3",
    "ini": "^1.3.5",
    "init-package-json": "^1.10.3",
    "is-cidr": "^2.0.6",
    "json-parse-better-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "lazy-property": "~1.0.0",
    "libcipm": "^2.0.2",
    "libnpmhook": "^4.0.1",
    "libnpx": "^10.2.0",
    "lock-verify": "^2.0.2",
    "lockfile": "^1.0.4",
    "lodash._baseuniq": "~4.6.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "~4.5.0",
    "lodash.union": "~4.6.0",
    "lodash.uniq": "~4.5.0",
    "lodash.without": "~4.4.0",
    "lru-cache": "^4.1.3",
    "meant": "~1.0.1",
    "mississippi": "^3.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.1",
    "move-concurrently": "^1.0.1",
    "node-gyp": "^3.8.0",
    "nopt": "~4.0.1",
    "normalize-package-data": "~2.4.0",
    "npm-audit-report": "^1.3.1",
    "npm-cache-filename": "~1.0.2",
    "npm-install-checks": "~3.0.0",
    "npm-lifecycle": "^2.1.0",
    "npm-package-arg": "^6.1.0",
    "npm-packlist": "^1.1.11",
    "npm-pick-manifest": "^2.1.0",
    "npm-profile": "^3.0.2",
    "npm-registry-client": "^8.6.0",
    "npm-registry-fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "npm-user-validate": "~1.0.0",
    "npmlog": "~4.1.2",
    "once": "~1.4.0",
    "opener": "^1.5.0",
    "osenv": "^0.1.5",
    "pacote": "^8.1.6",
    "path-is-inside": "~1.0.2",
    "promise-inflight": "~1.0.1",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "qw": "~1.0.1",
    "read": "~1.0.7",
    "read-cmd-shim": "~1.0.1",
    "read-installed": "~4.0.3",
    "read-package-json": "^2.0.13",
    "read-package-tree": "^5.2.1",
    "readable-stream": "^2.3.6",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "retry": "^0.12.0",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.2",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
    "semver": "^5.5.0",
    "sha": "~2.0.1",
    "slide": "~1.1.6",
    "sorted-object": "~2.0.1",
    "sorted-union-stream": "~2.1.3",
    "ssri": "^6.0.0",
    "stringify-package": "^1.0.0",
    "tar": "^4.4.6",
    "text-table": "~0.2.0",
    "tiny-relative-date": "^1.3.0",
    "uid-number": "0.0.6",
    "umask": "~1.1.0",
    "unique-filename": "~1.1.0",
    "unpipe": "~1.0.0",
    "update-notifier": "^2.5.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validate-npm-package-license": "^3.0.4",
    "validate-npm-package-name": "~3.0.0",
    "which": "^1.3.1",
    "worker-farm": "^1.6.0",
    "write-file-atomic": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": [
    "abbrev",
    "ansicolors",
    "ansistyles",
    "aproba",
    "archy",
    "byte-size",
    "cacache",
    "call-limit",
    "bluebird",
    "bin-links",
    "chownr",
    "ci-info",
    "cmd-shim",
    "columnify",
    "config-chain",
    "debuglog",
    "detect-indent",
    "detect-newline",
    "dezalgo",
    "editor",
    "figgy-pudding",
    "find-npm-prefix",
    "fs-vacuum",
    "fs-write-stream-atomic",
    "gentle-fs",
    "glob",
    "graceful-fs",
    "has-unicode",
    "hosted-git-info",
    "iferr",
    "imurmurhash",
    "inflight",
    "inherits",
    "ini",
    "init-package-json",
    "is-cidr",
    "json-parse-better-errors",
    "JSONStream",
    "lazy-property",
    "libcipm",
    "libnpmhook",
    "libnpx",
    "lockfile",
    "lodash._baseindexof",
    "lodash._baseuniq",
    "lodash._bindcallback",
    "lodash._cacheindexof",
    "lodash._createcache",
    "lodash._getnative",
    "lodash.clonedeep",
    "lodash.restparam",
    "lodash.union",
    "lodash.uniq",
    "lodash.without",
    "lru-cache",
    "meant",
    "mkdirp",
    "mississippi",
    "move-concurrently",
    "nopt",
    "normalize-package-data",
    "npm-audit-report",
    "npm-cache-filename",
    "npm-lifecycle",
    "npm-install-checks",
    "npm-package-arg",
    "npm-packlist",
    "npm-pick-manifest",
    "npm-profile",
    "npm-registry-client",
    "npm-registry-fetch",
    "npm-user-validate",
    "npmlog",
    "once",
    "opener",
    "osenv",
    "pacote",
    "path-is-inside",
    "promise-inflight",
    "query-string",
    "qrcode-terminal",
    "qw",
    "read",
    "read-cmd-shim",
    "read-installed",
    "read-package-json",
    "read-package-tree",
    "readable-stream",
    "readdir-scoped-modules",
    "request",
    "retry",
    "rimraf",
    "semver",
    "sha",
    "slide",
    "sorted-object",
    "sorted-union-stream",
    "ssri",
    "tar",
    "text-table",
    "uid-number",
    "umask",
    "unique-filename",
    "unpipe",
    "update-notifier",
    "uuid",
    "validate-npm-package-license",
    "validate-npm-package-name",
    "which",
    "write-file-atomic",
    "safe-buffer",
    "worker-farm",
    "tiny-relative-date",
    "cli-columns",
    "cli-table3",
    "node-gyp",
    "lock-verify",
    "stringify-package"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "deep-equal": "~1.0.1",
    "marked": "^0.5.0",
    "marked-man": "~0.2.1",
    "npm-registry-couchapp": "^2.7.1",
    "npm-registry-mock": "~1.1.0",
    "require-inject": "^1.4.3",
    "sprintf-js": "~1.1.1",
    "standard": "^11.0.1",
    "tacks": "^1.2.7",
    "tap": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dumpconf": "env | grep npm | sort | uniq",
    "prepare": "node bin/npm-cli.js --no-audit --no-timing prune --prefix=. --no-global && rimraf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j4 doc",
    "preversion": "bash scripts/update-authors.sh && git add AUTHORS && git commit -m \"update AUTHORS\" || true",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "tap": "tap --reporter=classic --timeout 300",
    "tap-cover": "tap --reporter=classic --nyc-arg='--cache' --coverage --timeout 600",
    "test": "standard && npm run test-tap",
    "test-coverage": "npm run tap-cover -- \"test/tap/*.js\" \"test/network/*.js\" \"test/broken-under-*/*.js\"",
    "test-tap": "npm run tap -- \"test/tap/*.js\" \"test/network/*.js\" \"test/broken-under-*/*.js\"",
    "test-node": "tap --timeout 240 \"test/tap/*.js\" \"test/network/*.js\" \"test/broken-under-nyc*/*.js\""
  },
  "license": "Artistic-2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm start` does not work because you do not have required dependencies. *cross-env: not found*
2. Share your `package.json` so we can define the real issue.
3. Answering to your question

   > Why it's looking for a packages/react-error-overlay/ directory?

   Seems that you have `postinstall` script. Read more about `pre` and `post` hooks here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

---

P.S. With invalid `postinstall` script in `package.json` you should get next error:

`error Failed at the test@1.0.0 postinstall script.`

Seems that you removed `name` and `version` form `package.json`, that is why your error is next:

`error Failed at the undefined postinstall script.`

That `undefined` in logs can confuse you

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the reply. I have **cross-env** installed. I have attached my npm package.json to the question now if you could kindly take a quick look?

Comment: em... so you cloned `npm/cli` repository and trying to install dependencies? :)